# VBA about dragging and multi-select checkboxes

Tags: excel, vba, select, checkbox, drag

Any Excel VBA code can process selecting or unselecting checkboxes in the dragged area by mouse and shade the area at the same time? The attached image is what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No. VBA userforms don't allow selecting checkboxes by dragging.